# Unable to handle kernel paging request?

Tags: kernel, virtual-memory

[Disclaimer: I was initially a little nervous about posting this here, so I asked on Meta if discussing homebrew / modding was acceptable. Based on the response I've gotten from several veteran members, I've gone ahead and posted this thread. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81554/is-it-okay-to-ask-questions-on-the-stackexchange-network-that-pertain-to-console) is the link on Meta.]

I'm currently trying to mod my original Xbox using xboxhdm and ndure 3.0. xboxhdm is built around a small bootable Linux distro, and it's giving me fits, so I figured that I'd ask here and see if anybody could give me a hand. (Note: Before anybody suggests a different board, xboxhdm boots from CD on a PC - the Xbox hardware is completely uninvolved in the process, so that's why I'm asking here.)

The PC I'm using is relatively old - it's an old Compaq desktop with about 512mb RAM and a 2.5ghz processor (likely a P IV). I'm using it because it has 2 IDE ports on the motherboard. The age of the computer shouldn't be an issue, performance-wise - the xboxhdm + ndure hack has been around for years - it was designed to run on such hardware.

Anyway - at one point in the process, I have to copy some files from the CD to the Xbox hard drive (which is a standard Seagate IDE drive, powered by a Molex). About halfway through the copy, everything just dies... I get an `unable to handle kernel paging request` error, and eventually a kernel panic.

I couldn't find anything about this error and how it specifically relates to Xbox modding, but what information I could find suggested that I might have a bad stick of RAM. I've not been able to test this yet, but I'm going to run MEMTEST as soon as I get home.

I don't have the setup with me - I'm at work, and it's at home - but if anybody's interested in lending a hand, I'll take pictures tonight and post them up. The only reason that I'm asking here is because I'm still a fairly new *nix convert, and I'm not quite sure how it all works. I'm assuming that `unable to handle kernel paging request` is a fairly standard error message, too... correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A “paging request” means that the kernel has tried to access some memory that it should have been able to access. If it can't and you see this message, there is either a hardware bug (almost always bad RAM) or a kernel bug. If it's a kernel bug, the numbers in subsequent messages are needed to track it down, but it's often still very hard to go from the location in the code where the error is detected to the location where the erroneous code actually is.

Comment: Yeah, tracking it down via the numbers is way over my head, so if it's not bad RAM, then I'll just use a different method. The system has 2 sticks of RAM in it, so I'm hoping that I'll just have to take one out. I'll post back with details in a few hours - thanks for the help, man.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Gentlemen, I think we have a winner...]

Well. How's that for fried RAM? Guess that was the culprit, after all.

I'm pleased to report that, after removing the defective stick, everything is going quite smoothly.